# Maintain Full Height without content overflowing

Tags: css, safari, overflow

I was working on a page and I created a 2 column layout with the central content in a `#wrapper` and then I made both columns the same height.

Column 1 has more content than Column 2, so to achieve the same equal height, my code is:

CSS:

`#col1 {
   width: 70%; height: 100%;
   min-height:30em; float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}`

`#col2 { width: 30%; height:100%; min-height:30em; float: right; margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

`#wrapper { width: 70%; height: 100%; min-height:30em; margin: 0 auto; }`

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
  ...
  </head>
<body>

<header><h1>Title</h1></header>

<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="col1">
Content here
Content Here
Content Here
Content Here
Content Here
  </div>

  <div id="col2">
   Some Content
  </div>

</div>
<footer>
 <p>Footer Content</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

My Content in `#col1` overflows in Safari but not the other browsers. Does anybody have a solution for this issue? I have played around with the height and min-width properties but hadn't found a way to get the Safari browser to comply.

My goal was to make the page responsive, `#col1` and `#col2` with them expanding to full hieght regardless of content (and without overflow).

If my question is unclear I can clarify.

Cheers!

***Edit***

I had also tried to use a few media queries, for example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
#col1, #col3, #wrapper { min-height: 35em; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
#col1, #col2, #wrapper { min-height: 40em; }
}
```

I thought that if I extended the min-height each step of the browser dimensions re-sizing, that both columns would, in effect, grow and accommodate the overflow text.

Comment: Full height of what? the window?

Comment: And you don't want the footer to overflow the page either?

Comment: I should have specified a bit more, for this instance, the header and the footer are both 5em. I don't what the content from either of the columns to overflow into the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `min-height: 30em` so you always run the risk of overflowing, depending on size of the screen you're looking at.  How about using the old 100% height content with a fixed height footer at the bottom?

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/8Hkz2/2/

Not that the box-sizing rules I put in won't work for IE7.

Comment: Your jsfiddle maintains good layout while the page is 100% width and height, but once you adjust the screen into smaller dimensions, the content within the columns become covered/hidden.

Comment: And once we get into those dimensions you would like the columns to scroll??

Comment: Once the footer gets close to the above columns content - say 2em - then I want the footer to stop. It's kind of like a vertical fluid layout, if that makes sense. Ultimately, if the content is dynamically changed with JS or another language, the columns will accommodate the content and the footer will stay below it.

Comment: Like I said, the code seemed to work fine in all other browsers, but Safari had a different reaction. Going to check the Safari website

Comment: I checked the CSS reference for Safari to see if `min-height` was supported and it is, since 1.3, so there must be something over-riding it. Both columns are elastic as well, so maybe their stretching dimensions have something to do with the lack of effect with `min-height`?

Comment: Is this fiddle getting closer? http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/y49pA/2/ - I've switch to using `display: table-cell` for the equal column height and put your min-height back in.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is closer, but I don't think the columns expand to fit content over 30em.

Comment: I think they do. Have you tested it by adding more content into the fiddle? Thought it was working for me.

Comment: you are right davidpauljunior, thank you! I should have experimented more with your jsfiddle first.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: The value of the `min-height` property overrides both `max-height` and `height`. So as both `#col1` and `#col2` are in `#wrapper` that has 100% height, you should only specify a `min-height`.

In terms of the overflowing text in Safari, have you tried adding `text-overflow: ellipsis;` or `text-overflow: clip;` to `#col1`?

Comment: See I do want the text to remain displayed in the columns. I don't want the footer to cover up any text. I had also just tried your suggestion, `text-overflow: ellipsis (or clip)` and had no effect.